# Voice/SMS testing API or call lists

Tags: twilio, phone-call, voice, twilio-php

I am building an app using Twilio to send out text messages and phone calls. It works great but I know there are limits to the amount of messages to send out per number in any given day. The app is going to be used to send out messages in the thousands at times, for instance to alert contacts about weather cancellations.

Since I am still developing, I do not want to send out real messages to thousands of real numbers a bunch of times while I test and configure my code.

Is there any phone apis, lists, etc. of dummy numbers that can be used as my example contacts that will at least return some form of TRUE that the number exists and received my call/message? Or return something else if I hit a use limit because of the number of messages I am sending.

I think I could get everything setup with a list of 1000 numbers since I can plan out every 250-500 calls, do this or that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are no lists like that that I know of.

You do have a set of [test credentials that you can use to send messages to a few "magic" numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-sms-messages) that will behave as if the message was successful (or failed for some reason). However there's only one success message here.

The thing about the limits of 200-250 messages per number per day is that they aren't hard limits. They are just around the level that carriers will start to consider blocking your messages. At that point you will likely still get a positive response from the Twilio API as a message is queued to be sent, but it may or may not fail at delivery time.

I recommend you look into [Twilio's messaging services](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/services-and-copilot), they allow you to create a number pool that messages are sent from. If you are sending a number of the same messages at the same time, you can also check out [Twilio Notify for sending notifications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications). I recently wrote up a blog post on [how to set up a messaging service, number pool and Notify for bulk SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/12/send-bulk-sms-twilio-node-js.html).

Let me know if that helps at all.